# Turning iteration into recursion

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.x, iteration

I want to check if the `string` user entered has a balanced amount of `(` and `)`'s

ex. `()(` is not balanced
    `(())` is balanced

```
def check(string):

        counter=0
        string=string.replace(" ","")

        if string[0] is "(":

           for x in string:
                if x is "(":
                        counter=counter+1
                elif x is ")":
                        counter=counter-1

           if counter1 is 0:
                print("Balanced")
           else:
                print("Unbalanced")
        else:
                print ("Unbalanced")
```

so this works, but how do I solve this problem with recursion? I am trying to think how I can make a variable decrease each time i call it recursively and once it's 0, stop.s

Comment: Your algorithm gives false positives for strings like `)(`.

Comment: A stack would be a good data structure to use here.

Comment: @dan04 Same false positives for the two answers too. All should short circuit everything when a count is less than zero to return unbalanced.

Comment: I guess [Recursive method for parentheses balancing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18007995/recursive-method-for-parentheses-balancing-python) is related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A direct, equivalent conversion of the algorithm would look like this:

```
def check(string, counter=0):
  if not string:
    return "Balanced" if counter == 0 else "Unbalanced"
  elif counter < 0:
    return "Unbalanced"
  elif string[0] == "(":
    return check(string[1:], counter+1)
  elif string[0] == ")":
    return check(string[1:], counter-1)
  else:
    return check(string[1:], counter)
```

Use it like this:

```
check("(())")
=> "Balanced"

check(")(")
=> "Unbalanced"
```

Notice that the above algorithm takes into account cases where the closing parenthesis appears *before* the corresponding opening parenthesis, thanks to the `elif counter < 0` condition - hence fixing a problem that was present in the original code.

Comment: Could easily fix that with `elif counter < 0: return "Unbalanced"`

Comment: @Óscar López  How do I make it so that if (has_letters_here) also return unbalanced?

Comment: @Jenny And why is that unbalanced? balancing only refers to matching parenthesis. Anyway - it'd be a simple matter of adding one extra case: if the character at index `0` is not `(` or `)`, then it's unbalanced according to your definition

Comment: @Sylwester I wasn't sure if `)(` is "unbalanced" according to OP's definition, I believe she's only interested in the _number_ of parenthesis. But anyway, I updated my answer with your suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> def check(mystr, barometer=0):
...     if not mystr:
...         return barometer
...     elif mystr[0] == "(":
...         return check(mystr[1:], barometer+1)
...     elif mystr[0] == ")":
...         return check(mystr[1:], barometer-1)
...     else:
...         return check(mystr[1:], barometer)
... 
>>> for s in ["()", "(()", "(())", "()()"]: print(s, check(s))
... 
() 0
(() 1
(()) 0
()() 0
```

`0` means you're properly balanced. Anything else means you're not balanced

Comment: won't this give a false positive for `)(`?

Comment: damnit! I forgot the `0` check on the last elif.