# How to add matching start tag in HTML

Tags: html, htmlcleaner

I have html content which looks like

```
<body>Hello world</div><div>New day</div></body>
```

I would like to parse this html snippet and add a starting div tag before Hello.
What is the approach I could follow? I tried to use [HTMLCLeaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) but it didnt help
Basically what this means is find ending div tags without matching start div tags and add them.

Comment: If you use java try using `Jsoup`. Something like `Jsoup.clean("<body>Hello world</div><div>New day</div></body>", Whitelist.relaxed());`

Comment: Just tried that and it gives me "Hello world <div> New day </div>"

Comment: This is an interesting question. Most parsers won't try to insert the opening tag because there's no way to tell where it ought to go; technically, it could go anywhere from the start of `body` to the start of the closing `div`. Is there some pattern to how these start tags are going amiss that can be used to predict where they should be inserted?

Answer (score 2):

If you use java try using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). Something like

```
Jsoup.clean("<body><div>Hello world</div><div>New day</div></body>", Whitelist.relaxed());
```

This will give you the proper output string.

**UPDATE**

You can use `Jsoup.parse(html)` which returns a `Document` on which you can call `toString()` to get the fixed html which will include all the `html` and `body` tags as well. It will give you the following output for you html.

```
   <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <div>
        Hello world
      </div
      <div>
        New day
      </div>
    </body>
   </html>
```

As you said most of the parser will fix the end tags but not start tags as they can not decide on where to start the start tags except just before the wrong end tag and it will be useless to add the start tag there just before the end tag.

You may need to implement you own logic for that as Trevor Hutto's suggestion (Stack based approach) bellow but it will have its own complications depends on your requirement.

Comment: I just tried that. It gives me Hello world
<div>
 New day
</div>

Comment: What I would expect is "<body><div>Hello world</div><div>New day</div></body>"

Comment: Yes, it removes the invalid tags. It just acts as if it is a browser, because, it can not predict on where to add the start tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a stack.

Push on open tags, then when you hit a close tag, pop and compare the popped tag to the one you just ran into.

So obviously, if you have a mismatch, and it is a div, you can do something.

Answer (score 1):

John Resig's [HTML Parser](http://ejohn.org/apps/htmlparser/) does a pretty good job of this. It's a little old, but it's still worked for a large majority of my use cases.

Edit: Actually, it seems to only fix missing closing tags, not opening tags...though some tweaks might be able to have it do the latter.

Comment: Exactly, thats what I am looking for. All the parsers only fix missing closing tags but none add missing start tags... Really does no one parser does what I need ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same technique that's used in parenthesis balancing, except instead of returning True/False, you would fix the tag instead. I did this for a work project once:

[Recursive method for parentheses balancing [python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18007995/recursive-method-for-parentheses-balancing-python)

What Trevor is describing is the same thing I'm describing (used in parenthesis balancing).

Answer (score 0):

I have created a **Javascript/jQuery** solution to add missing starting tags:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/DdbL7/)/Watch [Fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/DdbL7/show/)

Add **any HTML** to the body with missing tags like:

```
hello</h3>
<p>hai</p>
Welcome to fiddle</span>
</div>
```

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
var content;
var i;
var result="";
var previousTag="";

function exeq(){
    var a = content.lastIndexOf('<body>');
    var z = content.lastIndexOf('</body>');
    content = content.substring(a+6,z);

    while(i!=-1){
    var startAngle = content.indexOf('<');
    var endAngle = content.indexOf('>');
        i=endAngle;
    var ele = content.substring(startAngle,endAngle+1);
        if(ele.indexOf("/")!=-1)
        {
            if(previousTag != ele.replace("/",""))
                result = result + ele.replace("/","");
        }
    result = result + content.substring(0,endAngle+1);
    content = content.substring(endAngle+1);
    previousTag = ele;
    }

    /*Below part only to append result to body*/
    $('body').append('<h4>Result</h4><textarea>'+result+'</textarea>');
    /******************************************/
}

$.get(window.location.href,function(data){
    typeof(data)=="object"?window.location = window.location.href:
    content = data;
    exeq();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<div>Hello world</div>
<div>New day</div>
</body>
```

You can add a div before the hello world or you can remove the closing div after the hello world.
    
    Hello world
    New day

Answer (score -2):

You dont need a HTMLCLeaner or any tool, if you need to work with html is very simple just remember all tag <'something'> is close with a  or use a simple <'something'/> for summarize one!