# Making Parentheses Even?

Tags: python, string, recursion, python-3.x, parentheses

I'm trying to write a program that asks the user for a string input without using global variables. If the string has parentheses only side by side, then it's even. if it has letters, numbers, or the parentheses are spaced out, then it's uneven. For example, () and ()() is even, whereas (() and (pie) is not. Below is what I've written so far. Do I have to create more than one function for this problem?

```
def recursion():
    string = str(input("Enter your string: "))
    if string == "(" or ")":
        print("The string is even.")
    else:
        print("The string is not even.")
```

Comment: I think you need to read book on introductory Python. This problem can be solved in a single function, but it is going to use recursive.

Comment: Your `if` condition would always evaluate to `True` since you have a non empty string `")"` in the `or` condition.

Comment: you should think of your algorithm first a bit further. As it is now the program hardly works at all.

Comment: what are you trying to do? I am confused as to the point is. What you are trying to do. Is this an assignment? if so why don't you link it so we have an idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ummm.... `even = not string.replace('()', '')` meets the spec. as I understand it...

Comment: Also, to expand on what Sukrit is saying, your if statement is saying "If string == "(" or ")" " which is read as "If string == "(" " or " ")" " and since ")" is a non-empty string, it will register as True. Meaning: "if string == "(" or True)" Just adding clarity, because you seem to be even newer to this business than I am.

Comment: @AlexBaldwin actually the code I posted would give odd for `(()`...

Comment: Guys, why downvote this question?  The OP has clearly asked what they want and shown some work, they just don't have a depth of knowledge of programming.  Let's not make SO so unfriendly to new posters that make an effort of asking a good question.

Comment: @Jon, You're right, I totally misunderstood what was going you. You are quite correct and I am a humble novice, making errors everywhere I go! I deleted my comment. It was utterly useless.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turning iteration into recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006806/turning-iteration-into-recursion)

Answer (score 1):

A really useful stdlib script [shlex](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html) provides this type of parsing automatically and allows you to customize the behavior.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea about this.  Thank you.  Amazing how much of the language I use every day I really don't know that is hidden under the covers...

Answer (score 0):

I will collect much of the information in the comments into an answer.

First, in your posted code the line

```
if string == "(" or ")":
```

will always evaluate to `True` because a non-empty string is always `True`. What you have written is equivalent to:

```
if ( string == "(" ) or ")":
```

which is therefore equivalent to

```
if ( string == "(" ) or True:
```

which is *always* `True`.

Next, since it seems that you simply want to check if your string consists only of sets of '()', you can use Jon Clements' suggestion of `not string.replace('()','')`:

```
if not string.replace('()', ''):
```

Let's take a look at what this does:

```
>>> not '()'.replace('()', '')
True
>>> not '()()'.replace('()', '')
True
>>> not '(()'.replace('()', '')
False
>>> not '(pie)'.replace('()', '')
False
```

Last, you shouldn't call a variable string because it shadows a module in the standard library.  Something like `user_given_string` might work.

Summing it all up:

```
def recursion():
    user_given_string = input("Enter your string: ")
    if not user_given_string.replace('()', ''):
        print("The string is even.")
    else:
        print("The string is not even.")
```

Comment: Ah, I understand the "even = not string.replace('()', '')" line now. That is the best way to go about it, I think.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need to make multiple functions for this.  In fact, I would personally just do this:

```
def recursion():
    print("The string is not even." if input("Enter your string: ").replace('()','') else "The string is even.")
```

There really isn't a need to have a 6 line function for this job.  Instead, use a [ternary statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/ternary-conditional-operator-in-python) like I did to keep it concise.

Also, just wanted to mention this, there is no need to do:

```
str(input())
```

because `input` always returns a string in Python 3.x.